# To import .dat column into Oracle DB

Tags: oracle11g, teradata

we have exported one of the attachment table from Teradata and created the .tsv file and then each of the actual attachments ended up in a .dat file....

Example:

```
123|760103687|sample1.pdf|ATCHMNT_OBJ100.dat|Y|0|1/3/2013 07:18:36.000000|0|0
```

Is there any way to import the above type of records into Oracle DB or we have to convert this ATCHMNT_OBJ100.dat file into any other format.

Any of your help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a plain text file delimited by `|`. SQL*Loader can easily load that kind of file.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for your comments.. is there any way using SQL Developer.